# Is the map $F:(\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}, \phi \mapsto \phi(1)$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am supposed to prove or refute that $F:(\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}, \phi \mapsto \phi(1)$ is a linear map, with $(\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{R}}$ being the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$.

I know that for the mapping $F$ to be linear it has to satisfy

$$
F(a f)= aF(f) \quad \forall f \in (\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{R}}, a \in \mathbb{R}, \text{ and} \\  
F(f+g) = F(f) + F(g) \quad \forall f,g, \in (\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{R}}.
$$

I am pretty sure that this is not a linear mapping, but I am not sure how to prove this. I tried to come up with a counterexample but haven't been able to. I tried out constant, identity and functions using the absolute value, but these all seemed to satisfy the above conditions and I don't really know where to go from here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that th map is not linear? Have you tried testing the properties of a linear map?

Comment: There is something wrong with the question. If $\phi \colon \mathbb R \to  \mathbb R^2$ a map in the appropriate space, then $F(\phi) = \phi(1)$ is an element of $ \mathbb R^2$, not of $\mathbb R$. So $F$ cannot have codomain $ \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Daron I made a mistake there, $F$ is supposed to map to $\mathbb{R^2}$. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried proving $F$ is linear?

Comment: I am not really sure how I would go about that. I assume that I would just try to apply how addition and scalar multiplication is defined in a function space?

Comment: Yes, show that the map commutes with/preserves addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: You have the right idea. The only difficulty in this proof is figuring out what each definition means. Think of $\phi$ as a vector with $|\mathbb R|$ many entries, and each entry is a pair of real numbers. To add two vectors in this space just add the corresponding entries as 2-vectors. The function $F$ just spits out the first entry (2-vector) of what you feed it.

Comment: I had no idea how to visualize $\phi$, which is why I still wasn't really sure what I had to do, but that explanation really cleared it up. Thank you so much.